# How to estimate a recursive inequality with an upper bound

Tags: inequalities, sequences-and-series, induction

The below is a simplification of part of a proof I'm working on, in numerical analysis. It is similar to a paper that I studied some months ago, for which I got [some advice here on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292107/resolving-an-inequality-in-the-final-step-of-derivation-of-an-a-priori-energy).

I have non-negative sequences $A_k, B_k, C_k$ for $k=0\dots n$, a time-step $\Delta{t}$ and a positive number $p$ such that
$$(1+p\Delta{t})A_n + B_n \le A_{n-1} + B_{n-1} + C_n\Delta{t} \tag{$\star$}$$ and **I would like to claim** that the final solution with the unknowns $A_n$ and $B_n$ is bounded by their initial solution plus a finite quantity containing the maximum value of the known quantity $C_n$ i.e. there exists a bound of the form
$$A_n + B_n \le f(\Delta t) A_0 + g(\Delta t)B_0 + h(\Delta t)\max_{0 \le k \le n}C_k \tag{$\star\star$}$$
where I need to find the forms $f(\cdot)$, $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$.

**What I have tried:**

- I *removed* the non-negative $B_n$ on the left side of ($\star$) and got $$(1+p\Delta{t})A_n \le A_{n-1} + B_{n-1} + C_n\Delta{t} \tag{1}$$
- Proceeding in a similar way to the linked answer, I multiplied through by $(1+p\Delta t)^{n-1}$ and set $E_n = (1+p\Delta t)^nA_n$ to get
  $$E_n \le E_{n-1} + B_{n-1}(1+p\Delta t)^{n-1} + C_n(1+p\Delta t)^{n-1}\Delta{t} \tag{2}$$
- Applying recursion,
  $$E_n \le E_0 + \max_{0\le k \le n-1} B_k \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+p\Delta t)^k + \max_{0\le k \le n} C_k \Delta{t}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+p\Delta t)^k \tag{3}$$
- Now I divided by $(1+p\Delta t)^n$, and applied $A_0 = E_0$
  $$A_n \le \frac{A_0}{(1+p\Delta t)^n} + \left(\max_{0\le k \le n-1}B_k + \max_{0\le k \le n}C_k\Delta{t}\right)\frac{1}{(1+p\Delta t)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+p\Delta t)^k \tag{4}$$
- Simplifying and bounding the below by a geometric sum to infinity, we have
  $$\frac{1}{(1+p\Delta t)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+p\Delta t)^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1+p\Delta t)^k} < \frac{1}{p\Delta t} \tag{5}$$
- Using (5) in (4) gives
  $$A_n \le \frac{A_0}{(1+p\Delta t)^n} + \frac{1}{p\Delta t}\max_{0\le k \le n-1}B_k + \frac{1}{p}\max_{0\le k \le n}C_k  \tag{6}$$
  and the problems with this approach are

(a) There is no $B_n$ term on the left since I discarded it, and (b) the $B_{k-1}$ term on the right is an unknown. Only $B_0$ can provide a useful bound here.

I think if I don't discard $B_n$ in step 1, I might find a way to use recursion and end up with $B_n$ on the left and $B_0$ on the right. I have thought about summing from $0$ to $N$ but it's unclear how to proceed. Any suggestions on how to proceed will be very much appreciated.

---

I eventually figured it out (see answer below), but I am not certain because @losif's answer also seems irrefutable.

Comment: Consider setting Dn =  An + Bn, and see what you can say about the sequence D.  Gerhard "Fewer Variables Make Things Simpler" Paseman, 2018.09.13.

Comment: Thank you, I considered that but I hit a snag because of the $p\Delta{t}$ term that exists on the left for $A_n$ but not $B_n$. Any ideas how to approach this? I apologize if I am missing something obvious - I am a self-learner without extensive background in the field.

Comment: P.S. I would like to not use an exponential bound such as Gronwall's lemma, if possible, for stability reasons. It is also possible that this can't be proved this way, and I need to start over. But I want to be sure I am not missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$

The bound ($\star\star$) that you want is impossible in general. E.g., take $A_n=0$, $C_n=1$, $B_n=n\Delta t$ for all $n$, with $\Delta t>0$. Then ($\star$) will hold, whereas ($\star\star$) will not hold for large enough $n$, for any choice of $f,g,h$.

**Added:** The bound ($\star\star$) will hold with $f=g=1$ and $h=b:=\frac{K+1}p$ if we additionally assume that $A_n$ dominates $B_n$ in the sense that $B_n\le KA_n$ for some real $K>0$ and all $n$. Indeed, let $\de:=\Delta t$, $S_n:=A_n+B_n$, and $M_n:=\max_{0\le k \le n}C_k$. Then, with such $f,g,h$, ($\star\star$) can be rewritten as 
\begin{equation}
 S_n\le S_0+bM_n. \tag{!!}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, the condition $B_n\le KA_n$ can be rewritten as $(1+p\de)A_n + B_n\ge(1+\de/b)S_n$; so, ($\star$) yields 
\begin{equation}
 (1+\de/b)S_n\le S_{n-1}+C_n\de. 
\end{equation}
Now it is easy to to prove (!!) by induction. Indeed, for $n=0$ (!!) is trivial. Assuming (!!) holds with $n-1$ in place of $n$, we have 
\begin{multline}
 (1+\de/b)S_n\le S_{n-1}+C_n\de\le S_0+bM_{n-1}+C_n\de
 \le(1+\de/b)S_0+(b+\de)M_n \\ 
 =(1+\de/b)(S_0+bM_n),
\end{multline}
so that (!!) indeed follows.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I need to start all over again, then!

Comment: The bound you want will hold if $A_n$ dominates $B_n$ -- I have added details on this.

Comment: Hello again @losif, I think I proved this eventually - could you please help me take a look?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I eventually did**. In light of @losif's answer which I already accepted, can you please tell me what is wrong with my reasoning below?
Given ($\star$), we have
$$(1+pΔt)A_1+B_1 ≤ A_0 + B_0 + C_1\Delta{t} \tag{1}$$
and
$$(1+pΔt)A_2+B_2 ≤ A_1 + B_1 + C_2\Delta{t} \tag{2}$$
Adding a non-negative $p\Delta{t}A_1$ to the right side of (2), we get
$$(1+pΔt)A_2+B_2 ≤ (1+p\Delta{t})A_1 + B_1 + C_2\Delta{t} \tag{3}$$
and substituting (1) gives
$$(1+pΔt)A_2+B_2 ≤ A_0 + B_0 + C_1\Delta{t} + C_2\Delta{t} \tag{4}$$
Continuing in this way, we will obtain
$$(1+pΔt)A_n+B_n ≤ A_0 + B_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} C_k\Delta{t} \tag{5}$$
i.e.
$$A_n + \frac{1}{1+p\Delta{t}}B_n \le \frac{1}{1+p\Delta{t}}\left(A_0 + B_0 + n\Delta{t}\max_{1\le k \le n}C_k \right)$$
which means that
$$\min\left\{1,\frac{1}{1+p\Delta{t}}\right\}(A_n + B_n) \le \frac{1}{1+p\Delta{t}}\left(A_0 + B_0 + n\Delta{t}\max_{1\le k \le n}C_k \right)$$
and noting that $1 > \frac{1}{1+p\Delta{t}}$ for all $p > 0$ and $\Delta{t} >0$ leaves
$$\frac{1}{1+p\Delta{t}}(A_n + B_n) \le \frac{1}{1+p\Delta{t}}\left(A_0 + B_0 + n\Delta{t}\max_{1\le k \le n}C_k \right)$$
i.e.
$$ A_n + B_n \le A_0 + B_0 + n\Delta{t}\max_{1\le k \le n}C_k $$ which I set out to prove (except that the index of the max on the right, runs from 1, not 0), and this is okay in my case.

Comment: Yes, with the sum instead of the max and, therefore, with the extra factor $n$ before the max, there is no problem; the problem was only with the max per se.